# Apply the same function to each data member - Transform on heterogeneous types sort of thing

Tags: c++, c++11

Consider the following struct:

```
struct Test {
   char a;
   short b;
   int c;
   long long d;
   void transformTest() {
      // Pseudo
      foreach datamember (regardless of type) of Test
          call someTransform(datamember)
   }
};
```

We could also pass a lambda, function pointer, functor, whatever into the transformTest(), that's not my concern as of right now.

What's the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Wrap your data in a `tuple`.  Possibly a temporary one.

Step 2: Wrap your callable in a functor.

Step 3: Write a `tuple_foreach` that applies a functor to each element of a `tuple`.

For step 1, I'd advise leaving the data where it is, and just using a `std::tie` to create a `tuple` of references.

For step 2, a simple perfect forwarding functor looks like:

```
#define RETURNS(X) ->decltype(X) { return (X); }
struct foo_functor {
  template<typename... Args>
  auto operator()(Args&&... args) const
    RETURNS( foo( std::forward<Args>(args)... ) )
};
```

which represents the override set of functions called `foo`, and wraps that into a single object which automatically dispatches any call to the appropriate overload of `foo`.

For step 3, it isn't hard.  Just use the indexes trick to run code on each element of a `tuple`:

```
void do_in_order() {}
template<typename Lambda, typename... Lambdas>
void do_in_order( Lambda&& closure, Lambdas&&... closures ) {
  std::forward<Lambda>(closure)();
  do_in_order( std::forward<Lambdas>(closures)... );
}
template<unsigned... Is>
struct seq { typedef seq<Is> type; }
template<unsigned Max, unsigned... Is>
struct make_seq:make_seq<Max-1, Max-1, Is...> {};
template<unsigned... Is>
struct make_seq<0,Is...>:seq<Is...> {};

template<typename Tuple, typename Functor, unsigned... Is>
void foreach_tuple_helper( seq<Is...>, Tuple&& t, Functor&& f ) {
  do_in_order(
    [&]{ std::forward<Functor>(f)(std::get<Is>(std::forward<Tuple>(t))); }...
  );
}
template<typename Tuple, typename Functor>
void foreach_tuple( Tuple&& t, Functor&& f ) {
  foreach_tuple_helper( make_seq<std::tuple_size< typename std::decay<Tuple>::type >::value>(), std::forward<Tuple>(t), std::forward<Functor>(f) );
}
```

`do_in_order` doesn't work in clang last I checked, but an equivalent indexes trick that works on your compiler shouldn't be hard to google.

Comment: My "foo" takes 2 arguments. I added a constructor for the functor to store the other argument and then manually inserted the argument into foreach_tuple_helper -> std::forward<Functor>(f)(myArgAsDataMemberInClosure, std::get(stuff...)). It works but I don't suppose this is the correct way of doing things, as I have to augment the "generic" functionality itslef, so how do I pass in additional arguments? My call site looks like: do_in_order(tuple, myFunctor(thatExtraArgument));

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth Either use `std::bind` on a `foo_functor`, binding one argument, and leaving the other to be called, or write your own variation of doing that.  `do_in_order(tuple, std::bind( foo_functor, _1, fixed_argument ) )`, or something like that. (after pulling `using namespace std::placeholders` to get `_1` in view)

Answer (score 3):

The best way is to do it explicitly:

```
someTransform(a);
someTransform(b);
someTransform(c);
someTransform(d);
```

Of course, you'll need an appropriate number of overloads of `someTransform()`.

If you really, really don't like that, there's always [Boost Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/introduction.html).  With that you can put your values together in a structure which the library understands and then can iterate over.  This won't be worth doing for simple use cases.

Comment: Thanks, I will take a look at Boost Fusion, I am unfortunately not dealing with simple use cases :(.

Comment: OK.  Once you teach Fusion how to see your data, then it's just a matter of http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/algorithm/iteration/functions/for_each.html

Comment: Mmm, after taking a quick look, I think I'll end up wrapping everything in tuples and writing template machinery to unpack everything into that call.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds like a case for [Boost Fusion](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/quick_start.html) and its `for_each()` function combined with [BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_54_0/libs/fusion/doc/html/fusion/adapted/adapt_struct.html). This stuff can work some miracles! Here's an example on how you can do it:

```
#include <boost/fusion/include/algorithm.hpp>
#include <boost/fusion/include/adapt_struct.hpp>
#include <iostream>

using namespace boost::fusion;

struct Print
{
    template <typename T>
    void operator()( T && t ) const
    {

        std::cout << t << ' ';
    }
};

struct Test {
    char a;
    short b;
    int c;
    long long d;

    void printTest() const;
};

BOOST_FUSION_ADAPT_STRUCT(
    Test,
    (char, a)
    (short, b)
    (int, c)
    (long long, d)
    )

void Test::printTest() const
{
    for_each ( *this, Print() );
}

int main()
{
    const auto t = Test();
    t.printTest();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

While Boost.Fusion is a good solution, I thought I'd add that in C++11 you could use `std::tuple` like this:

```
    template <unsigned ... indices>
    struct sequence
    {
        typedef sequence type;
    };

    template <unsigned size, unsigned ... indices>
    struct static_range : static_range<size-1,size-1,indices...> {};

    template <unsigned ... indices>
    struct static_range<0, indices...> : sequence<indices...> {};

    template <class Function, class Tuple, unsigned ... indices>
    auto transform_impl(const Tuple & t, Function f, sequence<indices...>) ->
        std::tuple<decltype(f(std::get<indices>(t)))...>
    {
         return std::make_tuple(f(std::get<indices>(t))...);
    }

    template <class Function, class Tuple>
    auto transform_tuple(const Tuple & t, Function f) ->
        decltype(transform_impl(t, f, static_range<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>()))
    {
        return transform_impl(t, f, static_range<std::tuple_size<Tuple>::value>());
    }
```

The `sequence`/`static_range` classes have been invaluable in my code in expanding classes (not just `std::tuple`s) by indices so that I can `std::get` them.

Other than that, I think the code is fairly straightforward, it should be noted however that with this method the *order* in which `f` is invoked on each tuple element is undefined.

Usage would look like:

```
    std::tuple<char, short, int, long long> t;
    struct addone
    { template <class T> auto operator()(T t) -> decltype(t+1) {return t + 1;}};
    auto t2 = transform_tuple(t, addone());
```

The resulting tuple will not have the same types as the input tuple due to integral promotion, each will have type `typename std::common_type<T,int>::type`.

Comment: Yeah this is very similar to what I've ended up writing basically. Boost fusion appears to generate assembly, I can do all this stuff at compile time. I need this functionality to make sure I can spit out stuff into binary files with correct endian-ness, so I actually do this sort of "serialization". The problem is that I can't afford to have type promotion to swap the bytes properly (or don't swap at all in some cases). But yeahh, thanks :).

Comment: @ScarletAmaranth The type promotion was just as an example, I expected your usage to vary from this

Comment: I just mentioned it :).